# how to compute the limit of f(x)=(log x)^(log x)?

Tags: math

how to compute the limit of f(x)=(log x)^(log x)?
the logs have base 2. 
Is there a way to simplify the function further?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: need more info, log(x)^log(x) it's like x^x, for x->inf: f(x) -> inf

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28log%28x%29%5Elog%28x%29%2C+x-%3Einf%29 it's infinite.

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about the limit as x goes to infinity? The limit of log<sub>2</sub>(x) is infinity, and the limit of y^y as y goes to infinity is infinity; it follows that the limit here is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

There are three potentially interesting values which x might approach: 0, 1, and infinity.  As x approaches infinity, both the base ln(x) and the exponent ln(x) grow without bound, so the function goes to infinity.  As x approaches 0, serious problems occur because we take negative numbers (ln(x) is negative for 0<x<1) to strange powers -- impossible over the real numbers.  The function would not be defined.  As x approaches 1 (from the right), the function takes the so-called "indeterminant form" 0^0, which can be solved using L'Hopital's rule by taking logs (again!).  I think you'll find log(x)^log(x) approaches 1, regardless of the base of the logarithm.

Comment: The limit as x tends to zero is minus infinity.

Comment: before we compute the limit can we simplify this problem further?

Comment: @Hammerite:  According to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28log%28x%29%5Elog%28x%29%2C+x-%3E0, the limit as x approaches 0 is 0.

Comment: Whoops, brain fart. I was thinking of log_2(x). You are doubtless correct.